# How do I specify 3 interrupt transfers per microframe in high-speed USB?

Tags: usb

I am sending interrupt transfers over USB 2.0 and trying to get the maximum bandwidth possible.  According to various documents, they indicate that "the endpoint descriptor may specify up to 3 interrupt transactions per microframe".  I can't find any way in the endpoint descriptor to specify this.  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 5.9 of the USB 2.0 Specification says:

> A high-speed interrupt or isochronous endpoint indicates that it requires more than 1024 bytes per microframe when bits 12..11 of the *wMaxPacketSize* field of the endpoint descriptor are non-zero. The lower 11 bits of *wMaxPacketSize* indicate the size of the data payload for each individual transaction while bits 12..11 indicate the maximum number of required transactions possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, it now appears that windows does not support high-bandwidth Interrupt endpoints. :(